# Can function be called after speficic element is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

Is there any way to call function after speficic element is loaded?

Something like this:

```
var element = $('.elements-class');
element.on('load', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

**EDIT (Better explanation):**

After DOM is ready, I have  element and inside that element is couple of images and some text. So, I want to animate that  block after it's loaded, and all it's childs. I don't want to wait the rest of the page to be loaded. Only that specific element, in this example the  element.

Comment: Use `document.ready`, or the callback of an AJAX call if that's where you're adding the HTML. The `load` event does not work reliably for elements other than `img` and `object`

Comment: And I'm not aiming for <image>, but for <div> or <header> element...

Comment: I'm not adding anything. Everything is already in .html file. I'm trying to start animations on speficic elements when they are done with loading. Something like, animating "above the fold" content after it is loaded, if you know what I mean.

Comment: If it's a static HTML file then there isn't any incremental loading of the elements; the browser renders the whole page at once.

Comment: If you are asking to do something after an *animation* has finished, then *loaded* is the wrong word. Also, this has been asked before.

Comment: $(document).on('load change','yourselector',function(){  your business logic...  })

Comment: How can I say this any clearer? After DOM is ready, I have <header> element and inside that element is couple of images and some text. So, I want to animate that <header> block after it's loaded, and all it's childs, but I don't want to wait the rest of the page to be loaded. Only that specific element, in this example the <header> element.

Comment: There is no event for something like that. You would have to implement something that checks the load status of the individual images first (if that’s what you want to wait for?), and then triggers whatever you want to run when that’s the case for all of them.

Comment: @RobiZzT I updated my answer to match your edit, let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this comment in your question

> I'm not adding anything. Everything is already in .html file. I'm trying to start animations on speficic elements when they are done with loading. Something like, animating "above the fold" content after it is loaded, if you know what I mean.

You can wait for the `document.ready` event. `<div>` or `<header>` elements don't support `load` or `ready` events to attach to, `load` event is usually aimed to elements that load a remote resource like an `<img>`.

Doing this:

```
$(function () {
    //Do something
});
```

You ensure the code in the callback is executed when the document finishes loading.

---

To follow up your edit. You can insert `<script>` tags into the dom and they will be executed in the order they are inserted. For example:

```
<div>
    <h1>Fancy title</h1>
    <script>
        /*
            here you can put code to manipulate dom elements inserted
            before this script tag.
            Trying to do $('p') here will not find the element because
            is not already in the dom.
        */
    </script>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: I know how document.ready works. Is there any way I can wait for element to load after DOM is ready. Like, is there any synonym for window.on('load'), but for speficic element?

Comment: That element you are expecting to load comes from some AJAX response or is appended **after** the document is ready? Because if not, you should use document.ready.

Comment: While page is loading, everything loades in order. But, for example, images are loaded on window.on('load'). But I don't want to wait whole page to be loaded. Only my first element (<header>) and all images in that element.

Answer (score 1):

As you have everything already in your HTML and you want to do some action/call some function you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //add your code here
});
```

Refer to JQuery documentation to understand better how .ready function works.

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the
>   entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

If you also want some function to always execute something when the element changes you can attach the .change() to this element, as you can see below:

```
<form>
  <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

bind event to all elements with class target.

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

This will trigger the alert inside change function everytime the DOM has changed on the attached elements.

Comment: So, answer is: No, I can't check if specific elements (and it's children elements) are loaded. Thank you.